# Why do Candelas and Howard say that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left( n \kappa \epsilon \right) \ = \ - \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, dirac-delta-distributions

In the paper [Vacuum $\langle \phi^2 \rangle$ in Schwarzschild Spacetime by Candalas and Howard](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1618), they say that for each non-zero $\epsilon$ it is true that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left( n \kappa \epsilon \right) \ = \ - \frac{1}{2}
$$

This is equation (2.7) in the paper, where $\kappa$ is a constant (later set as the surface gravity for the black hole) and $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$ is taken as a regulator.

In what sense is this true? As some kind of distributional statement? Because this doesn't converge in the strict sense.

Comment: Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n\rho} \cos (nx)$ instead and then take $\rho \to 0^+$ which gives $-\frac{1}{2}$. At this stage you can take $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$III(x)~=~  \delta(x-\mathbb{Z})~=~ \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} \delta(x-m)~=~\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{2\pi i xn}~=~1+2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\cos(2\pi xn)$$
is the [Dirac comb/Shah distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb).

Comment: So for $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ (which is going to be true for $ x = \kappa \epsilon/(2\pi)$ if $\epsilon$ is small enough), then we have $\delta(x - \mathbb{Z}) =0$ and from which the identity follows?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.